# Having trouble with owlcarousel width

Tags: html, css

http://makarskarivijera.hr/

this is what the .html says

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-6">
    <div class="owl-carousel" id="homeCarousel">
      <div class="item">
      <img src="images/brela.jpg" alt="brela makarska">
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

this is what i get when inspect

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-6">
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="homeCarousel" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
<div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
<div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 3918px; left: 0px; display: block; -webkit-   transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); -webkit-transform-origin: 326.5px 50%;">
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 653px;">
<div class="item">
<img src="images/brela.jpg" alt="brela makarska"/>
```

i would like to change that width: 653px but i have no idea where to find that

if someone can share the information that would be very nice :)
thx

Comment: Hi @user3123165,

I have very similar problem like your one. Could you able to find the solution for this?

Answer (score 10):

look in your javascript files for "`.owlCarousel(`"  It should be a function that runs and controls the owl carousel.  Its nothing to do with owl.carousel.min.js but rather a function that invokes that code.  I have something like this:

```js
.owlCarousel({
   items: 10,
   rewindNav: false
});
```

Change the `items:10` and it should change your width per pic.  Then you can add to your function things like -

```js
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({ 
   items: 10,   
   itemsDesktop: [1199,10],
   itemsDesktopSmall: [980,9],
   itemsTablet: [768,5],
   itemsTabletSmall: false,
   itemsMobile: [479,4]
})
```

Look for "Customizing" - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

Comment: this helps me, saved my time!! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```css
/* corrects margin between slides */
.owl-item img {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I was having trouble finding the correct selector, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The width is set by the plugins javascript with an inline style based on the available screen width divided by the amount of items.

You have 6 items in your slider.
Total wrapper width of 3918 divided by 6 items is 653px per item.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me was to just resize the image within the owl item.  I did not mind the extra whitespace around the image.  I added the following code to my CSS file:

```css
.owl-item .item {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 185px; /* This is with the expectation that there are 4 items for the carousel, set in Theme/js/main.js */
}
```